# Angular - lazy load component in content projection

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to build a tabs-component, where the content of the currently opened tab should be initialized lazily. My goal was, to have a usage that looks something like this:

```html
<tabs>
 <tab-content title="foo">
  <some-component></some-component>
  <some-other-component></some-other-component>
 </tab-content>
 <tab-content title="bar">
  <a-different-component></a-different-component>
 </tab-content>
 <tab-content title="baz">
  <some-component></some-component>
  <a-different-component></a-different-component>
 </tab-content>
</tabs>
```

What I noticed was, that the inner components were initialized together with the components where the tabs were declared, even though the template for a single tab uses `*ngIf` around `<ng-content>`. This example shows the same behavior:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'late-init',
  template: '<ng-container *ngIf="active"><ng-content></ng-content></ng-container>'
})
class LateInitComponent implements OnInit {
  active: boolean = false;

  constructor(private readonly _changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.active = true;
      this._changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
    }, 2000);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<late-init><log-component></log-component></late-init>`
})
export class AppComponent {}

@Component({
  selector: 'log-component',
  template: ''
})
class LogComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { console.log(`constructor`); }
  ngOnInit(): void { console.log(`ngOnInit`); }
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LogComponent,
    LateInitComponent
  ],
  imports:      [BrowserModule],
  providers:    [],
  bootstrap:    [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Running this example prints `constructor` and `ngOnInit` immediately to the console. What would I have to change, to have the component initialized after the `late-init` timer has expired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out by looking at the [source of `*ngIf`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/8b1a2f104864afd2aa7b7c938c01dcf1d973fd6f/packages/common/src/directives/ng_if.ts). It now looks like this:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[late-init]',
})
export class LateInitComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private readonly _viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
              private readonly _templateRef: TemplateRef<any>) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => this.render(), 2000);
  }

  private render() {
    this._viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this._templateRef)
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<ng-container *late-init><log-component></log-component></ng-container>`
  // I could use <log-component *late-init> here, I just wanted to make clear that using 
  //   multiple components with the @Directive / *template approach works too
})
export class AppComponent {}
```